# Yii and bootstrap: How debug jQuery when I get a strange behavior?

Tags: jquery, debugging, yii, firebug

I have a problems developing an Yii application with jQuery. Using Firebug, when I click in a tab, I can see the navigator makes a lot of calls: twice to the home page, four to the original destination, etc; but I can't see how happens. The calls occurs and I don't know where. However, if I could debug and see where exactly the calls are made, I'm pretty sure that I could resolve it.

My question: how debug jQuery in this case?

**Edit:** Thank you for your help. I explain more about this problem. This is the design of the webpage. When I click in the "Zones" tab, I load a webpage in the contentarea_zone. It have tabs too (the tabs are courtesy from Bootstrap extension for Yii, who use jQuery too)

[image]

When I click on the tab "Description", I see the calls in the Firebug console.

[image]

But I can't see where they come from. And if I read to the right of Firebug console, I see "jquery.js" and line numbers, but the jQuery library have only 9405 lines. I don't know why Firebug reports calls in the line 10079, 10692, etc.

I'm really lost. If the problem remains unclear, it would help me a lot if you recommend me a suitable tool or method for debugging this case...

**Edit 2:** thanks to your recommendations, I started to using Firebug with its options. I found that the library that causes the repeated calls is bootstrap.js. It seems that, at finishing to load the tab "Description", it have accumulated "callbacks". But, I still don't know where these callbacks come. Some ideas?

Comment: I suggest using breakpoints within your javascript debugger of choice.  I personally use Chrome's version.  I believe Firebug can do this as well.  Edit: you will need to do some searching of documentation to see how this is done.  Both are well documented and a simple web search will reveal many answers.

Comment: Do you mean ajax calls??

Comment: I edited my question with more information about the problem... I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after using Firebug and the keyword "debugger" in some points, I could find the problem origin. The click was bubbling, triggering events that should not have been triggered. A simple line like

```
e.stopImmediatePropagation()
```

fixed the problem, making that jQuery stops bubbling after first click.

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 3):

place the keyword

```
debugger;
```

from where you want to debug the code. the code execution will break there and from firebug console you can step into,over the code and step by step follow the execution of the code

[TIPS and TRICKS](http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/debugging-javascript-code-with-firebug-1899)